# C# get string/characters value from c++ function which return char pointer

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, char-pointer

I've a DLL written in C++. A function of this DLL is like the following code:

C++ code:

```
     char _H *GetPalette() {

            -------Functions body

            -------Functions body

            return pPaletteString;

      }
```

Now I want to get the Pallet String from that GetPalette() function in C# code.

How could I get string from that function?
I've tried this in C# code. But could not get the correct result.

C# code:

```
    [DllImport("cl.dll", EntryPoint = "GetPalette@0", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]

    private static extern IntPtr libGetPalette();

    public IntPtr GetPalette()
    {
        return libGetPalette();
    }
```

Finally I want to get string like this

```
            IntPtr result;
            result = imgProcess.GetPallet();

            string pallet;
            pallet = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(result);
            MessageBox.Show(pallet);
```

This code does not work properly.
Can some body plz help me, How could I get the string value from my C++ DLL function?

Thanks

Shahriar

Comment: It is good practice to define what error or behavior you are getting. How can we know what does "This code does not work properly" mean?

Comment: I've got '-->' characters from that code. But it should return as like '473757.473767.574767.............' string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your C++ function in C# code with string return type.

```
[DllImport("cl.dll")]
private static extern string GetPalette();
```

And than simply call it from in your C# code.

```
string palette = GetPalette();
```

Within `DllImport` attribute you might need to set correct calling convention `CallingConvention` and character encoding `CharSet`

Comment: I think you might want to explain the onwership semantics of the returned buffers (IIRC .NET will free the memory with free()?)

Comment: Thanks Lukas Kabrt. Your answer is 100% correct. I've used CharSet=CharSet.Ansi and changed my functions return type as string. And now I'm getting the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

You've told C# that the calling convention is `__stdcall` but there's no evidence of `__stdcall` marking on the function itself. In addition, `char*` could be UTF-8.

Comment: Actually, I'm new in .net Interoperability/Marshalling . I've  used this stdcall convention code from other sources. May be I'm wrong. So what can I do now to get string from that C++ DLL function? Thanks

Comment: Changing your C# code to match the calling convention of the C++ code would be a start.